# Why are two of my boxes at different heights when using the same css class?

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't see why my flexboxes are not all obeying the same `padding-bottom` rule. Only one class is applying the height through `padding-bottom`.

```css
.col-t {
  width: 100%
}

.col-s {
  width: 50%
}

main#container .grid .grid-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

main#container .grid .grid-container .box {
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

main#container .grid .grid-container .box>div {
  padding-bottom: 56.66666%;
}

.r {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: blue
}

.p {
  background: purple
}
```

```html
<main id="container">
  <section class="grid">
    <div class="col-s grid-container">
      <div class="col-t box">
        <div class="r">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-s box">
        <div class="b">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-s box">
        <div class="p">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Is it because the height through padding-top and bottom is relative to the width? But if this is the case, how would it be possible to make all of the boxes the same height using percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because the height through padding-top and bottom is relative to
>   the width?

Yes

> But if this is the case, how would it be possible to make all of the
>   boxes the same height using percentages?

Since the `col-s box` element is only half the width of the `col-t box`, you need to double its childrens padding's percent, `padding-bottom: calc(2 * 56.66666%);` to make them have the same height as the `col-t box`'s child has.

Stack snippet

```css
.col-t {
  width: 100%
}

.col-s {
  width: 50%
}

main#container .grid .grid-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

main#container .grid .grid-container .box {
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

main#container .grid .grid-container .box>div {
  padding-bottom: 56.66666%;
}

main#container .grid .grid-container .col-s.box>div {
  padding-bottom: calc(2 * 56.66666%);                     /*  added  */
}

.r {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: blue
}

.p {
  background: purple
}
```

```html
<main id="container">
  <section class="grid">
    <div class="col-s grid-container">
      <div class="col-t box">
        <div class="r">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-s box">
        <div class="b">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-s box">
        <div class="p">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```